# How else can we say "what number are you in the line"?

Tags: synonyms, questions

Is there any way to rephrase "what number are you in the line"?

Comment: Do you really care what number in line they are or do you really want to know "How many people are in front of you?"

Answer (score 1):

There is no special way to say this. You can ask what the person's *position* in line is. But *number in line* is about as good as it gets.

Comment: We'e probably use 'queue' in the UK.